# Qt, не работает сеть после переноса на другой компьютер

Tags: qt

Написал приложение на Qt. Приложeние использует `QNetworkAccessManager`. В системе где стоит Qt Creator все работает отлично. Проблем нет. Но после переноса на другую систему сеть просто выключается. Ничего не работает. Никаких ошибок не возникает. Просто ни один запрос не доходит до сервера. Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть причина? Код не привожу, так как он рабочий полностью, иначе не работал бы на моей системе.
В папку с проектом положил: 
`

```
Qt5Core.dll
Qt5Gui.dll
Qt5Network.dll
Qt5Widgets.dll
Qt5Multimedia.dll
libstdc++-6.dll
libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll
Папка platforms с содержимым:
qminimal.dll
qoffscreen.dll
qwindows.dll
```

`
При первом запуске была ошибка файла MSVC140.dll. Решил установкой redistributable Visual C++;

Как выяснилось ошибка следующая. Error creating SSL context;
Добавил libeay32.dll, ssleay32.dll. Но ошибка все равно осталась

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что программа запускается, работает в штатном режиме без ошибок, но не делает того, что от нее ожидается?

Comment: Да. Все правильно. Программа не выполняет ни одного https запроса.

Comment: В таком случае я сильно сомневаюсь в вашем "Код не привожу, так как он рабочий полностью, иначе не работал бы на моей системе."

Comment: Так на моем компьютере все работает идеально. Но стоит мне запустить программу на виртуалке, ничего уже не работает.

Comment: Это может говорить о том, что в вашем коде есть что-то, что привязывает его корректное исполнение к этой конкретной машине - ip адрес, мак-адрес, наличие каких-то служебных файлов, еще что-то. Это самое очевидное, что приходит в голову.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ. Сейчас попробую в этом ключе поискать.

Comment: @Андрей Беспалов для выполнения https запросов, Вам скорее всего нужно рядом с программой положить OpenSSL библиотеки.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ. Сейчас попробую.

Comment: Не могли бы Вы подсказать, где находятся эти библиотеки? что-то не могу найти их никак.

Comment: Да. Проблема однозначно с ssl. Я вывел отладочную информацию на консоль на виртуальной машине. Ошибка: Error creation SSL context. Плюс еще много разных ошибок связанных с ssl. Скачал openssl, добавил от туда libeay32.dll, ssleay32.dll Но к сожалению эти ошибки остались.

Comment: @Андрей Беспалов Возможно еще нужен libssl32.dll

Comment: Добавил, но все равно эффекта нет. Видимо потому, что я скачал не те dll. Пожалуйста. Подскажите где взять правильные dll? Я просто с этим ни разу не сталкивался. Первый раз программу на QT собираю.

Comment: Если ошибка в отсутствии DLL или в неправильных DLL, то это можно обнаружить с помощью Dependency Walker. Не забывайте также смотреть зависимости самих DLL.

Comment: @maestro Благодарю Вас за ответ. Сейчас попробую.

Comment: Всем большое спасибо. проблема была в нехватке библиотек ssl. Поэтому не https не работал.

Answer (score 0):

Немного странно, что у Вас с программой лежат библиотеки mingw, а при запуске требовало msvc14. Уверены что Qt*.dll взяты из правильного каталога? Лучше используйте утилиту windeployqt, она сама найдет нужные для Вашей программы библиотеки и плагины.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ. Да я однозначно использовал файлы из правильного каталога. Было проверено неоднократно. Сейчас попробую использовать утилиту, которую Вы посоветовали.

Comment: Попробовал утилиту, которую Вы посоветовали. Она добавила еще файлы, но сеть все равно не работает.

Answer (score 0):

https://evileg.com/ru/post/163/ - соберите приложение через windeployqt, все необходимые библиотеки и внешние зависимости подтянутся в папку сборки. Хорошо, если почитаете про InnoSetup, как с его помощью инсталляторы собирать.